# How to create multi threading php script?

Tags: php, multithreading

I'd like to create linux daemon (in php), it will run an internal timer to manage my php scripts. (ie.: frontend cache update, data pre processing etc. these are existing services, now we run  each script in bash with "nohup")

So my question is, how can i create single thread for each started process? At all possible do it with php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multithreading in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325667/multithreading-in-php)

Comment: Get the OS to run the scripts (possibly on a cron), it will manage the number of threads and you will not have to worry about any of it. Also, PHP does not support threading.

Comment: if it must be done in php, look into php fork. `pcntl_fork` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: i prefer to use an os independent manager layer. And also i need sql based event and queue management. (administrator can edit timing and piority of processing, change item positions in queue if need etc. )

Comment: @JustinWood yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pthreads](http://pthreads.org/) extension for multithreading, but a cronjob for every script sounds more convenient for your case.

Comment: Thanks, its look good. But now i have another problem, maybe you can help me. When i try to install it: "No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pthread""

Comment: I don't know what you tried but you can check the comments section here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php Also note that extension requires ZTS enabled PHP. If it's not enabled in your version, you have to compile PHP with ZTS enabled option.